# How to split a text file in multiple files?

Tags: python, parsing, text

I extracted a text file with the following format:

```
user1
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
33643334383262616539323337343966353463303464626331396638373435376565383963366463
3037383439333665636136653165613631336538313662660a656132393966613839373563636463
31356165663036643535306563393663363462316661613435313133666234656361326433356366
6637623462316363360a343066323363626633383631303032633334626365353734363862663332
3636

user2
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
65663365353466313564306261666634316137343438623432353030343832326632346333663332
6232393236626563326630383639636337346465386664320a663363643836663266613366313030
31313836336461303863366338613236323631336264363632316561646663663431306633333036
6562633430656630390a323034616232353430396261303436623037663665363736613530336431
6135

user3
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
35346138316166343430643434396566343761666361343935386464343638376532343566356331
6134393664646666626637643035373961613931353334360a626565336466316336313863313466
64383061323966316261656231613538663162666236386136396430663433343134303131326434
3461666634333437350a613766636361393236633262613739653962643732643135363561333534
6332

user4
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
62633764663030333566373434303632343030353163363661303066636431383936306264373235
3266316631383930303832643265316630353236323437350a356338316261616137633632333961
62646234363237383838366361383235393638376239386264333361373438616530323338656436
3836373463386663370a356164383538643131373337376638656236633630313433326362333334
6139
```

I need to split the file by each newline to receive files which are named after the user(1,4) and only contain the ansible secret.

What I tried:

```
from sys import argv

with open(argv[1], "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        fname = ""
        secret = []

        if line.startswith("user"):
            fname = line

        elif line.startswith("\\$ANSIBLE"):
            secret.append(line)

        elif line[0].isdigit():
            secret.append(line)

        elif len(line.strip()) == 0:
            f = open(fname, "x")
            for i in secret:
                f.write(i)
            f.close()
        
        else:
            print("This is not supposed to happen.)"
```

I get a `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` so far and feel like this is the most inefficient method possible.

Comment: I would first check to see if your indents are correct

Comment: Try `lines = file.readlines()`. Then it's easier to debug how many lines you get etc.

Comment: Change `print("This is not supposed to happen.)"` to `print("This is not supposed to happen.")`. So, swap the last two characters of your file.

Answer (score 0):

```py
print("This is not supposed to happen.)"
                                     # ^ typo here!
```

@JANO found it but posted in comments.